# How do I do a windows registry wait loop in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Intune is giving me the S**t's I am trying to install a program with Powershell and usually, you just put -wait at the end and the scrips wait's until the install is done and then closes but with intune it just hangs.

so what I want to do is put in a wait loop so that when this windows registry is created

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{AA3C5F33-570B-3989-8542-D5DC0F759221}

With this name field equaling this number
DisplayVersion = 21.1.21.45

Below is attempt at the PowerShell script

```
$regkey = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AA3C5F33-570B-3989-8542-D5DC0F759221}'
$DisplayVersion = '21.1.21.45'
$Notdone = $true

DO {
    $exists = Get-ItemProperty -Path $regkey -Name $DisplayVersion -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if (($exists -ne $null) -and ($exists.Lenght -ne 0)) {
        & "C:\Autodesk\{D138465E-4098-4F01-B453-1C4BEADE75D8}\image\installer.exe" -ArgumentList "-i deploy --offline_mode -o C:/Autodesk\{D138465E-4098-4F01-B453-1C4BEADE75D8}\image\Collection.xml --installer_version 1.35.0.9"

    $Notdone = $false
    }
    else {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
    }
} While ($Notdone)
```

Comment: Your code looks good. What's the problem with it? Any error?

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: Typo on $exists.length

Comment: @brendansmith, take a look at Doug's comment - flip `ht` to `th`.

Comment: still doesn't work, it just hangs

Comment: I think the problem is that it is not reading that I need the display version to be 21.1.21.45

Comment: Is `-ArgumentList` supposed to be there?

Comment: i get this when i put that in 'At line:1 char:37
+ $DisplayVersion = 'DisplayVersion'  -ArgumentList  '21.1.21.40'
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-ArgumentList' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:52
+ $DisplayVersion = 'DisplayVersion'  -ArgumentList  '21.1.21.40'
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token ''21.1.21.40'' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code that worked for me

```
[Version]$minVersion = "21.1.21.45";
do {
  $version = [Version]'0.0.0.0'; try { [Version]$version = [Version](Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AA3C5F33-570B-3989-8542-D5DC0F759221}' -EA 0).DisplayVersion; } catch { }
  if ($version -ge $minVersion) {
  #Write-Host "The version is now '$($version)', which is greater than the Minimum version '$($minVersion)'";
  }
  else {
  #Write-Host "The version is now '$($version)', which is less than the Minimum version '$($minVersion)'. Will wait 15secs.";
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 15;
  }
}
until($version -ge $minVersion);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

you restart the installation every 15 seconds

```
$regkey = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AA3C5F33-570B-3989-8542-D5DC0F759221}'
$DisplayVersion = '21.1.21.45'
$Notdone = $true

Start-Process "C:\Autodesk\{D138465E-4098-4F01-B453-1C4BEADE75D8}\image\installer.exe" -ArgumentList "-i deploy --offline_mode -o C:/Autodesk\{D138465E-4098-4F01-B453-1C4BEADE75D8}\image\Collection.xml --installer_version 1.35.0.9" -Wait -NoNewWindow

DO {
    $exists = Get-ItemProperty -Path $regkey -Name $DisplayVersion -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($exists)){
    
        $Notdone = $true
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
    }else {$Notdone = $false}

} While ($Notdone)
```